# Getting FileNotFoundError exception on Pytorch 0.4, python 2.7 - after applying fix

Tags: pytorch

I'm working with Pytorch 0.4, I got the  FileNotFoundError Exception in functional.py when it invokes the binary_cross_entropy loss. Here is the stack trace:

```
loss += torch.mean(F.binary_cross_entropy(F.sigmoid(out0), all0) +
```

File "/home/local/.../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1483, in binary_cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce)
RuntimeError: cudaEventSynchronize in future::wait: device-side assert triggered

I'm aware of this type of issues like https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6932. I added the fix in the locations suggested by the users in threads, however, the exception still occurs.  I'd be happy for any help.
Best,
S.